# How to generate text files starting from a parent text file

Tags: bash

I have list of text files, each text file contain numbers like this:

```
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
```

> the numbers in the text files are comma separated.

How can I generate 6 files (using bash) starting from every parent file. Every file of these 6 new files contain group of the numbers as follow:

```
file0.txt contain 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
file1.txt contain 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
file2.txt contain 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
file3.txt contain 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
file4.txt contain 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
file5.txt contain 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Are the output files supposed to contain a fixed number of fields, or just all the consecutive equal values?

Comment: @glennjackman. Thanks! Just the consecutive series of equal numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby works well for this:

```
ruby -e '
  ARGV.each do |filename|
    data = File.read(filename).strip.split(",")
    groups = data.group_by {|n| n}
    groups.each_pair do |n, nums|
      # you don't really say what your input filenames look like
      # I will assume they end with ".txt"
      f = filename.sub(/\.txt$/, "#{n}.txt")
      File.write(f, nums.join(" ") + "\n"}
    end
  end
' fileA.txt fileB.txt ...
```

Comment: Great!! it worked and this is what I really want. Thanks a lot genn I keep learning from you ;)

Answer (score 1):

one line answer using sed

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' InputFile.txt |while read line ; do     echo -n "$line ">>file$line.txt ;  done
```

Or multiline when in a shell:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' InputFile.txt |while read line
do 
    echo -n "$line ">>file$line.txt
done
```